# How does Windows determine what appears in the “Network” folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10

How does Windows determine what shares/resources appear in the Network folder? Is there a command line for repopulating or manually adding resources?

Example problem:

I have a NAS called DiskStation which I can access by manually typing "\DiskStation" in explorer's address bar. However, even after navigating to that share, it doesn't appear in the Network folder. The Network folder is not empty. I can see other computers on the LAN in this Network folder. (Windows 10)

At the same time, there are other Windows (< Windows 10) machines on this same LAN that automatically show this same "DiskStation" in their Network folder.

In case it matters, the DiskStation requires credentials to gain access. However, those credentials are being saved correctly, as the "\DiskStation" method opens directly without prompting for credentials.